# Cannot resolve method addArguments(java.lang.String) - Selenium with Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-rc

I'm new to Selenium and in my code I'm trying to use my default profile from chrome with the browser that the selenium opens (without the cookies.)
Here is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


public class tryf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\******\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\******\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //WebElement okStart;

        //okStart = driver.findElement(By.id("close-instructions"));

        //okStart.click();
    }
}
```

My problam is that the code won't compile, with that eror

```
Error:(15, 16) java: no suitable method found for addArguments(java.lang.String)
    method org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.addArguments(java.lang.String...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.lang.String[])
    method org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.addArguments(java.util.List) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.List)
```

Hope for help, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string parameter in following statement.

> options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");

The string parameter is not applicable as highlighted by the stacktrace.

> method org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.addArguments(java.util.List) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.List)

You can look at the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) to find which method meets your requirements.

The overloaded **addArguments** methods signature are below;

```
ChromeOptions   addArguments(java.util.List<java.lang.String> arguments)
Adds additional command line arguments to be used when starting Chrome.

ChromeOptions   addArguments(java.lang.String... arguments)
```